# How to I remove all the child element except the first element?

Tags: javascript

It is a BlackJack game. I have a container which the first child element is a template for cloning card purpose. How to I remove all the child elements except the first element? I think the current code which is the "clearContainer" method remove all child elements.

```js
function makeCardPlayer() {
    // .card is created in the template card css class
    var card = $(".card.templatePlayer").clone();
    
    //card.removeClass("templatePlayer");      
    card.addClass("newCard");              
    $("#cardContainerPlayer").append(card);        
}

function clearContainer() {
    debugger
    //$("cardContainerPlayer > *").slice(1).remove();

    var myNode = document.getElementById("cardContainerPlayer");
    var fc = myNode.firstChild;
    var sib = fc && fc.nextSibling;
    while (myNode.lastChild && myNode.lastChild !== sib) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
    }
}

makeCardPlayer();    
clearContainer();
```

```css
#cardContainerPlayer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .card {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top; 
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 26px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid 1px black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .newCard {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 26px;
        background-color: yellow;
        border: solid 1px black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .templatePlayer {
        /*display: none;*/
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="cardContainerPlayer">
    <div class="card templatePlayer">
      <span class="playerCardFace"></span>
      <span class="playerCardSuit"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here are the code which I have removed out extra codes for brevity.

Comment: You're including jQuery, but not using it much. Any reason you're not using it in `clearContainer`?

Comment: it doesn't work. It clears everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu seem to be avoiding jQuery in `clearContainer`. If you want to use it that function, then

```
function clearContainer() {
    $("#cardContainerPlayer > *").slice(1).remove();
}
```

That selects all child elements of the container and uses [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a set of only the ones after the first one, then removes them.

If you want to use the DOM directly:

```
function clearContainer() {
    var myNode = document.getElementById("cardContainerPlayer");
    var fc = myNode.firstChild;
    var sib = fc && fc.nextSibling;
    while (myNode.lastChild && myNode.lastChild !== sib) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Or you might use `firstElementChild`, `nextElementSibling`, and `lastElementChild`, depending on what you want to do and whether you need to handle text nodes in there. More on those various properties in [MDN's DOM documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Jquery approach but doesn't work but the pure JS approach works well.

Comment: @Steve - The jQuery version was missing a `#` -- fixed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the nextSibling() method to find and delete every sibling of the 1st child :

```
function clearContainer() {
    debugger
    var myNode = document.getElementById("cardContainerPlayer");
    var fc = myNode.firstChild;

    while (fc.nextSibling) {
        myNode.removeChild(fc.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `clearContainer()` method, you can use something like this

```
function clearContainer() {
  debugger
  var myNode = document.getElementById("cardContainerPlayer");
  var fc = myNode.firstChild;

  while (fc.nextSibling) {
    myNode.removeChild(fc.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

By removing the next sibling of the child, at the end you will be left just with the firstChild.